# When to use OpenGL vs GL on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

After fighting to get something to try to compile I realized some code needed to change:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include "OpenGL/gl.h"
#include "OpenGL/glx.h"
#else 
...
```

needed to change into:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__ 
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glx.h"
#else
#...
```

After installing Quartz. However, this also worked:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__ 
#include "OpenGL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glx.h"
#else
#...
```

But `OpenGL/glx.h` doesn't exist.

What do the different header locations on OS X mean? Why do I have two different places for OpenGL files?

Comment: Think of it as a directory structure (because it is). The system will look in the default include directories (and the local directory if " "'s are used, for whatever is in it. So they get expanded to <system_include_path>/OpenGL/gl.h and <system_include_path>/GL/glx.h

Comment: I should rephrase that better, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You're using the wrong kind of include path; I'm surprised this works at all. What you want is:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

Note the use of angle brackets instead of quotation marks and he capitalization of `OpenGL`.

(You may need to add the OpenGL framework to your project to make this work. If you aren't using XCode, add `-framework OpenGL` to your compiler flags.)

Second: Don't use `glx.h` in Mac applications. GLX is an extension to the X11 windowing system that provides support for GL -- it is primarily meant for use on UNIX/Linux systems that use X11 as their desktop interface. The macOS desktop interface is not based on X11, so you shouldn't need GLX.

---

An explanation of the paths:

- The `GL/` path on macOS refers to the X11 GL headers, which may be present if you have XQuartz installed. They are *not* what you want.
- `OpenGL/` refers to the OpenGL framework.